# addClass/removeClass and save in localStorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage

I have a switcher on a page to add / remove class to body tag. Click "Night" and class"night" is added to body and "day" class is removed and visa versa. I also want this to store in localStorage so if someone navigates away from page and comes back the relevant class is still added to the body. I've almost got it working. But when you come back to the page and switch class you need to refresh the page for the class to change. Also looking at my code, it seems a bit long winded. I'm sure if could be trimmed down and better executed. Here's what i have.

**HTML**

```
<div class="switcher">
    <p class="day active">Day</p>
    <p class="night">Night</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".night").click(function(){
    localStorage.setItem('screenModeNightTokenState', 'night');
});

$(".day").click(function(){
    localStorage.setItem('screenModeNightTokenState', 'day');
}); 

if(localStorage.getItem('screenModeNightTokenState') == 'night') {
    $("body").addClass("night");
    $("body").removeClass("day");
}

if(localStorage.getItem('screenModeNightTokenState') == 'day') {
    $("body").addClass("day");
    $("body").removeClass("night");
}

$('.day').click(function() {
    $("body").addClass("day");
    $("body").removeClass("night");
    $(".switcher .day").addClass("active");
    $(".switcher .night").removeClass("active");
});

$(".night").click(function(){
    $("body").addClass("night");
    $("body").removeClass("day");
    $(".switcher .night").addClass("active");
    $(".switcher .day").removeClass("active");
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arvmtz04/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you add the same class to the `body` as you use on the `p` elements to toggle the state. You can fix this by making the selectors for those toggles more restrictive, ie. `p.night`.

Also note that you can make the code more succinct as you have attached two event handlers each to the toggles which can be merged. You can also use only a single class to set the 'night' state, and have the 'day' state set as the default. Try this:

```html
<div class="switcher">
  <p class="day active">Day</p>
  <p class="night">Night</p>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  if (localStorage.getItem('screenModeNightTokenState') == 'night') {
    $("body").addClass("night");
  }

  $('.day').click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('screenModeNightTokenState', 'day');
    $("body").removeClass("night");
    $('.switcher p.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });

  $(".night").click(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('screenModeNightTokenState', 'night');
    $("body").addClass("night");
    $('.switcher p.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.switcher p {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.switcher .active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

body {
  background-color: #d2f4f7;
}

body.night {
  background-color: #5c3b1b
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/7cfyh1x4/) - this example works in the fiddle as SO snippets do not allow access to `localStorage`

Comment: Thanks Rory. I figured out it was because of the clashing class names. Thanks for the more succinct code, i knew there was a leaner way of coding this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think i've solved the issue. A lot of problems seem to be the fact i'm using the same class for the switcher and the class added to the body. I just changed the switcher p classes and it seems to work. Although i'm sure there is a tidier way of writing this code.